# C# Sudoku solver computation result in crash

Tags: c#, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

Okay I made this kind of program with c++ and got that to compile and compute a reasonable answer in under a second, no problem.
I tried to translate the program to c# because I wanted the nice graphical interface with textboxes and that sort that I can get with c# in visual studio. The algorithm is very similar, but the c# version won't produce the result before the program crashes, I have no idea why...

Further information for my program:
I have a list of 81 TextBox objects, and the initial array is iniatialized using a for-loop to give the right values to the right places in the two-dimensional array.

This array is then passed to the recursive function with the reference to the array and row and col = 0 as parameters (because c# wont compile with unasigned local variables). I have debugged the program to check if the right values were given to the rigth places in the array, no problems on that end.

Also using the debugger in Visual Studio I found out that the debugger used a vast amount of time to get from the first function call of the recursive function to the next.

Quick Norwegian guide: rad = row, kol = column. I hope it won't be to much of a problem.

Main: (it's a button event trigger)

```
        private void btnLøs_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int rad, kol;

        rad = 0; kol = 0;
        int[,] array = new int[9,9];

        for(int i = 0; i < 81;i++)
        {
            int tmpRad = i / 9;
            int tmpKol = i % 9;
            //Celler is the list of textblocks that represents the grid
            if(celler[i].Text == "")
            {

                array[tmpRad, tmpKol] = 0;
            }

            else
                array[tmpRad,tmpKol] = Convert.ToInt32(celler[i].Text);
        }

        LøsSodoku(ref array,rad,kol);

        for(int i = 0; i < 81;i++)
        {
            int tmpRad = i / 9;
            int tmpKol = i % 9;

            array[tmpRad,tmpKol] = Convert.ToInt32(celler[i].Text);

            celler[i].Text = array[tmpRad,tmpKol].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
private bool gridHarLedigPlass(ref int[,] arr, ref int rad, ref int kol)
 //check if the array has empty cells (cells with 0)    
    {
        for (rad = 0; rad < 9; rad++)
        {
            for (kol = 0; kol < 9; kol++)
            {
                if (arr[rad, kol] == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool tallIBox(ref int[,] arr, int startRad, int startKol, int num)
    {
        int tmpRad = startRad, tmpKol = startKol;

        for (int rad = 0; rad < 3; rad++)
        {
            for (int kol = 0; kol < 3; kol++)
            {
                if (rad != tmpRad && kol != tmpKol)
                {
                    if (arr[rad + startRad, kol + startKol] == num)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool tallIRad(ref int[,] arr, int rad, int kol, int num)
    //Check if the num exists in the row
    {
        int tmpRad = rad, tmpKol = kol;

        for (kol = 0; kol < 9; kol++)
        {
            if (rad != tmpRad && kol != tmpKol)
            {
                if (arr[rad, kol] == num)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool tallIKolonne(ref int[,] arr, int rad, int kol, int num)
    //Check if the num exists in the column
    {
        int tmpRad = rad, tmpKol = kol;
        for (rad = 0; rad < 9; rad++)
        {
            if (rad != tmpRad && tmpKol != kol)
            {
                if (arr[rad, kol] == num)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool erSafe(ref int[,] arr, int rad, int kol, int num)
    //Check if the placement is valid
    {
        return !tallIRad(ref arr, rad, kol, num) && !tallIKolonne(ref arr, rad, kol, num)
            && !tallIBox(ref arr, rad - rad%3, kol - kol%3, num);
    }

    private bool LøsSodoku(ref int[,] arr, int rad, int kol)
    //Recursive backtracking function
    {

        //Check if all cells are filled with numbers
        if (!gridHarLedigPlass(ref arr, ref rad, ref kol))
        {
            return true;
        }

        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (erSafe(ref arr, rad, kol, num))
            {
                arr[rad, kol] = num;

                if (LøsSodoku(ref arr, rad, kol))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                arr[rad, kol] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What are you passing as arguments to these methods?

Comment: You say the program crashes - what message do you get when it crashes? That might be useful.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to call it. But the cpu usage goes through the roof, and no matter how long it goes, it wont produce a result.

Comment: Have you considered keeping the game logic in C# and code just the UI in C# (you may need a C++/CLI layer if you don't want to use interop)?

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to see where your infinite loop is?

Comment: Can you put an example of an array that you would use so we could test out your methods?

Comment: @Zack I could, but I can't see the point since I'm 100% sure that the loop I have produces an correct array

Comment: @SindreWilting If you've got a problem, then seeing an example of an array that you're using will prevent people trying to guess what your problem is.

Comment: @SindreWilting OK, the loop wasn't there when I asked.

Comment: How long you have to wait until this condition `rad < (rad + 3)` gets false?

Comment: as far as I see you don't change `rad` or `kol` in your recursive call - so you will retry the same cell over and over again (you don't check first if it's already set either) - so my guess is that you missed to move to the next cell before calling `if (LosSodoku(ref arr, rad, kol))` - btw: why the `ref` for `arr`?

Comment: @Ralf Well, in the for-loop is pass the int rad. If i pass rad = 3 then rad will be rad - 0 = 3. 3< (3+3) is true for 3,4 and 5.
Did not understand your question?

Comment: I wanted to say that this condition is always true. Therefore the loop will never end. Same goes for the loop over kol

Comment: @Carsten I usually program in c++, I can never be sure if I pass a variable as reference or value. 
The other thing is that the rad and kol variables will change because of the if-statement at the top of the recursive function. It will find the first unasigned cell and then change the original value of kol and rad since they are passed as references

Comment: @Ralf The rad value is incremented by one in the for-loop, it will stop being true once rad reaches rad + 3

Comment: the variable is on both sides and changes on both sides. 1<4 and 1000000<1000003. You can change rad anyway you like but rad will always be smaller then rad+3.

Comment: @Ralf Now I see Ralf, if that is the problem, then that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Or to be even more clearer you presumably wanted tmpRad on the right side of that condition not rad. And tmpKol instead of kol.

Comment: @Ralf I changed the code and got the program to produce a result. It's not a correct result, but it atleast got rid of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem, but why the program produced wrong results hurts my brain.
Apearantly what I had to do was to remove the tmpRad and tmpKol checks in each of the different sudoku tests to produce the right results.

Now it works like a charm.